# some category image not showing magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, category-image

My Code is

```
$_obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $_obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($cat_id);
$fullCategoryPath = $category->getImageUrl();
echo $fullCategoryPath;
```

It is working for **some categories** and not working for some categories. But both have **category image**.

Comment: are the images set in the correct scope?

Comment: yes, echo $category->getImage(); this code return also blank for some categies.

Comment: I'm talking about store-scope

Comment: Please post the solution at the answer section

Comment: @AmitBera it was a configuration error on OPs side. no need to post an answer